# Adjust size of image when the window's height is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

With reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33467545/positioning-nav-bar-at-the-bottom-of-the-viewport-which-also-always-remains-at-t) question. I am trying to adjust size of image/slider when the height of browser is resized, the effect i am trying to achieve is [here](http://jeanstories.com/) . I tried using max-height and max-width to the div, also used bootstrap img-responsive class, but its not working. Any idea , how to do this?

```css
#topbar{
  display:block;
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
  height: 30px;
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#073860;
  top:0px;
  display:block;
}
#head{
  background-color:#ededed;
  height:500px;

}

#logo{
  font-family: 'lainiedayshregular';
  display: block;
  height:134px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 29px 0px 0px;
  padding: 20px 20px 5px;
  font-size:3em;
}
#logo a{
  position:relative;
  height: 109px;
  width: 377px;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#073860;
  font-size:2em;
}

nav{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height: 56px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  bottom:0px;
  display:block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
  background: #FFF;
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
  font-weight:600;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

nav ul li {
  display:inline;
  text-decoration:none;
}

nav ul li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color:#073860;
  outline: 0px none;
}
.menu{
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px;
  position:sticky;
  top:30px;
}
.navbarlogo{
  font-family: 'lainiedayshregular';
  color:#073860;
}
#test{
  height:1000px;
  background-color: #fafbf9;
}
#footer{
  border-top: 1px solid #EDEDED;
  background-color: #FFF;
  height: 37px;
  z-index: 3;
  bottom: -35px;
  transition: bottom 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <!--CSS Links-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"><!--Custom stylesheet--> 
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>-->
    <title>Title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="topbar"> </div>
    <div id="logo"><a href="#">
      Layla
      </a> </div>
    <div id="head" class="row" style="vertical-align:middle; text-align:center; max-width:100%; height:auto;">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.freelargeimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Landscape_01.jpg" style=" max-width:60%; height:auto; image-rendering: optimizequality"/>
    </div>
    <nav class="menu">

    </nav>

    <div id="test" class="row"></div>
    <footer id="footer" style='display:none; position:fixed; bottom:0px; left:0px; width:100%;'>footer test</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can try using vh unit for your height. http://generatedcontent.org/post/21279324555/viewportunits

Comment: Thanks, I used your suggestion, and its exactly what i wanted. @Michael Pon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try these three steps :

1. Set html and body height `html,body{height: 100%;}`
2. Set the container height `#head{height: 60%; max-height: 60%;}`
3. Set the img height `#head img{height: 100%;width: auto;}`

The result is in the snippet

```css
#topbar{
  display:block;
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
  height: 30px;
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#073860;
  top:0px;
  display:block;
}
#head{
  background-color:#ededed;
  height:500px;

}

#logo{
  font-family: 'lainiedayshregular';
  display: block;
  height:134px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 29px 0px 0px;
  padding: 20px 20px 5px;
  font-size:3em;
}
#logo a{
  position:relative;
  height: 109px;
  width: 377px;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#073860;
  font-size:2em;
}

nav{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height: 56px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  bottom:0px;
  display:block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
  background: #FFF;
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
  font-weight:600;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

nav ul li {
  display:inline;
  text-decoration:none;
}

nav ul li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color:#073860;
  outline: 0px none;
}
.menu{
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px;
  position:sticky;
  top:30px;
}
.navbarlogo{
  font-family: 'lainiedayshregular';
  color:#073860;
}
#test{
  height:1000px;
  background-color: #fafbf9;
}
#footer{
  border-top: 1px solid #EDEDED;
  background-color: #FFF;
  height: 37px;
  z-index: 3;
  bottom: -35px;
  transition: bottom 0.6s ease-in-out 0s;
}

html,body{height: 100%;}
#head{height: 60%; max-height: 60%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;}
#head img{height: 100%;width: auto; }
```

```html
<div id="topbar"> </div>
<div id="logo"><a href="#">
  Layla
  </a> </div>
<div id="head" class="row">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.freelargeimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Landscape_01.jpg"/>
</div>
<nav class="menu">

</nav>

<div id="test" class="row"></div>
<footer id="footer" style='display:none; position:fixed; bottom:0px; left:0px; width:100%;'>footer test</footer>
```

Comment: Its working perfectly, when i use single image, but with 3rd party slider, I have to make lots of changes in configuration of slider, so i used suggestion by @Michael Pon from comments, and it was exactly what i wanted. I am accepting this answer, as its work, according to the question.